# Iterating through all float values with Java

Tags: java, floating-point, reinterpret-cast

I'm developing a math function and would like to test its output at every float value within a range. I have already done this in C++ but now I want to compare the performance to Java. How do I iterate through all float values in Java?

In C++, I'm simply iterating through the necessary range with an unsigned int, then reinterpreting it as a float pointer

```
float *x = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&i);
```

However, how can this be done in Java? Preferably quickly, as I am testing the performance (no String solutions thank you :D ). If there's no fast way, I guess I could just pre-calculate a million of them into an array and iterate through them. But that would mess up the cache performance, so I think using random numbers would then be better for my case, although it won't quite hit all values.

Comment: Note that accessing a `float` through reinterpret_cast<float *>(&i)` for an `unsigned int` `i` is not a proper way of reinterpreting bytes in C++. A proper way supported by the C++ standard is `float x; std::memcpy(&x, &i, sizeof x);`, provided `float` and `unsigned int` are the same size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Math.nextUp(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-float-) to get the next float number.

Example to print the next 100 floats starting from 1:

```
float n = 1f;
System.out.println(n);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    n = Math.nextUp(n);
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: Will `Math.nextUp(n);` generate `-0.0`?

Comment: @chux I didn't know the difference between `0.0` and `-0.0`, but testing the above code starting from `-0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f` does indeed generate `-0.0`, while `nextDown` from a positive number generates `0.0`.

Comment: I suspect `Math.nextUp(-0.0);` goes to same positive number as `Math.nextUp(0.0);` - thus skipping `0.0` when going up.  This meets OP's goal of "Iterating through all float _values_" even if it does not iterate though all `float` combinations like `Float.intBitsToFloat()`.

Answer (score 4):

In Java you can use method [`Float.intBitsToFloat(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat-int-):

```
for (int i = iMin; i < iMax; i++) {
    float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(i);
   ...
}
```

Comment: What `iMin` and `iMax` should be ?! Example?